# First order Wiener–Hopf filter design

Tags: filter-design, homework, adaptive-filters, random-process

> Consider a random process with auto-correlation function:
>   $$r_{\rm dd} [k] = \beta^{\lvert k \rvert}\quad\text{where}\quad 0 < \beta < 1. 
> $$
>   Suppose also that the observation is:
>   $$
> x[n] = d[n] + v[n]
> $$
>   where $v[n]$ is uncorrelated white noise with variance $\sigma^2$.
>
> Design a first order Wiener–Hopf filter to reduce the noise in $x[n]$ of the form
>
> $$W(z) = w(0) + w(1)z^{-1}$$

Comment: Is this homework? Can you show your attempt at solving this?

Comment: the w=R^(-1)  *  p  , which R  is the correlation matrix of X[n] and p is the cross-correlation vector between d[n] and X[n].  i should compute the inverse of  R and p to solve the function to get the W. is that right? it is my opinion.

Comment: @HaomingLi , your question should have the homework tag.

Comment: -1 for removing the `homework` tag.

Comment: Sorry about that, i am fresh here and i update it now, my  solution above is correct or not plz guide me 0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refer to the notation from the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter#Finite_impulse_response_Wiener_filter_for_discrete_series).

Your received signal is $x[n]$, and its Autocorrelation is given by
$R_x[n]=R_d[n]+R_v[n]$ when noise and signal are uncorrelated. Hence,

$$
R_x[n]=\beta^{|k|}+\sigma^2\delta[n]
$$

The cross-correlation between the received signal and the signal of interest is

$$R_{xd}[n]=E[d[n'](d[n'+n]+v[n'+n])]=R_d[n]$$

under the assumption again that signal and noise are uncorrelated.

Now, the Wiener-Hopf equation gets you

$$
\begin{pmatrix}R_x[0] & R_x[1]\\ R_x[1] &R_x[0]\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}w[0]\\w[1]\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}R_{xd}[0]\\R_{xd}[1]\end{pmatrix}
$$

Filling in the variables, we get

$$
\begin{pmatrix}1+\sigma^2 & \beta\\ \beta &1+\sigma^2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}w[0]\\w[1]\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\\beta\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now, you just need to solve for $w[0],w[1]$ to get your filter coefficients.